# Problems with populating select on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, forms

I know it looks like a dublicate here. But I think I have right code, but obviously not cause it aint working. What do i miss here? So what i intend is to read xml file and populate select on page load. Or document ready..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>xml to select</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $("#myDiv").append("<select id='mySelect'>");
      $(xml).find('value').each(function(){
        var a = $(this).text();
        $("#mySelect").append("<option class='nice' value='" + a + "'>" + a + "</option>");
      });
      $("#myDiv").append("</select>");
    }
  });
}</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thank you for your clear and understanding answer :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your xml ?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<heady>
 <txt>-</txt>
 <value>o</value>
  <txt>0-349</txt>
  <value>354.09</value>
   <txt>350-399</txt>
   <value>418.47</value>
 
</heady>

Comment: I dont know how to use mini md..

Comment: Tried your code and it seems to work. But I see a typo on your document ready. You have to close the bracket. `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: Oh yes. That little. I need a better linter if there is any. Thank you.